# wmic command returns no instance when accessing Win32_BaseBoard class

Tags: powershell, wmi

Why does Win32_BaseBoard return no instances in PowerShell?

```
wmic path "Win32_BaseBoard" get "Model"
```

Comment: That's not a PowerShell command - did you mean `gwmi Win32_BaseBoard -Property Model`? Also, what is your OS? Is this a virtual machine?

Comment: I am sure I can run this command in PowerShell and I am sure this it's ```wmic```. I am running it on a physical machine which is a Surface Pro 3.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why Does Win32_BaseBoard returns no instances in PowerShell?

```
wmic path "Win32_BaseBoard" get "Model"
```

The above is not a PowerShell command, it is a `wmic` command.

It returns no instances (an empty string) because the value `Model` has not been set by the manufacturer of your motherboard.

I have the same behaviour on my Sony laptop.

```
F:\test>wmic baseboard get product, manufacturer, version, serialnumber, model
Manufacturer      Model  Product  SerialNumber  Version
Sony Corporation         VAIO     N/A           N/A
```

Comment: Wait, isn't there a difference between a lack of instances and an instance with a blank value for a particular field?

Comment: @BenN I suppose there could be.

Comment: I am getting 'no instance available' rather than blank value. It's different. The command just returns fine the other day. What could be the cause of getting 'no instance'?

Comment: @xtu No idea :/